# How do Stack Exchange communities deal with spam?

Tags: support, spam-detection

This is a high-level question that may appear "obvious", but it's not, otherwise it would be addressed in the FAQ.

I believe the answer is, "community members take care of spam and spammers after they appear, manually, and there is no pro-active filtering performed by the software to block fresh spam and new spammers"

...but I'm not positive.

Sadly, not everyone can use Stack Exchange for their communities, but everyone can learn from Stack Exchange, hence my question.

I want to know how spam is dealt with, and how effective the methods are.

Comment: You largely have the answer already. Mods and Managers have some tools to make it easier, of course, but it's all basically manually detected. Pretty effectively, too.

Comment: 1.  Captchas
2.  Spam Flags
3.  Moderation

Comment: Nice try, spammer.

Comment: It's people! Stack Exchange's spam filter is made out of people!

Answer (score 5):

On a site as famous as Stack Overflow, a post is removed is it receives 6 flags marking it as offensive, spam, un-useful or any other reasons you may or may not think of. This of course, is for the community members like you and me and so on.

However, [moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) have the ability to *force* delete them.

Certain kind of questions are not allowed by default as a feature from SE team. But overall, it is still all user managed.